# How do I convert this SQL query that uses row value comparison into a sequelize query?

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, orm, sequelize.js

I have this SQL query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM funds
WHERE (fund_id, created_at) > ($1, $2)
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

...that I am trying to convert into a [sequelize (v6)](https://sequelize.org/) filter object for the `findAll(...)` query.

I have an index for `(fund_id, created_at)` and I am using sqlite as the database.

My objective with the query is to be able to use keyset pagination using `(fund_id, created_at)`.

So far this is what I have:

```js
{
  where: {
    [Op.and]: [
      { fundId: { [Op.gt]: prev_fund_id } },
      { createdAt: { [Op.gt]: prev_created_at } },
    ],
  },
  limit: 5,
  order: [["created_at", "DESC"]],
}
```

This doesn't exactly convert into the expected SQL query I mentioned above as shown by the log of the SQL query passed to my sqlite database:

```sql
SELECT `fund_id`, `name`, `description`, `created_at`, `updated_at` FROM `funds` WHERE (`fund_id` > '04e5b202-e62e-417a-b9d8-8cd5b6a1cb8f' AND `created_at` > '2023-02-13 07:38:36.683 +00:00') ORDER BY `created_at` DESC LIMIT 5;
```

The headache that I am running into is converting the `(fund_id, created_at) > ($1, $2)` expression...

I am fairly new to SQL and I believe (correct me if I am wrong) that `(fund_id, created_at)` is not equivalent to using the `AND` logical operator in SQL. Yet `sequelize` doesn't seem to have any operators (`Op`) for that expression...

How should I use sequelize to create this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    const { Op } = require("sequelize");

Fund.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.and]: [
      { fund_id: { [Op.gt]: $1 } },
      { created_at: { [Op.gt]: $2 } },
    ],
  },
  order: [["created_at", "DESC"]],
  limit: 5,
})
  .then(funds => {
    // handle the results
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // handle the error
  });
```

I hope I understood well what you want to do